# jQuery não retorna para o HTML

Tags: jquery

Não consigo escrever o retorno dentro do elemento HTML em caso de sucesso,
ele escreve o `console.log`, mas não no html.

Código:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{

    $('.comentarios').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.texto').prepend("<div>inicio da funcao<div>");
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: url_destino,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (retorno) {
                console.log(retorno);
                 $(this).siblings('.texto').prepend("<div> info</div>");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: O primeiro .prepend() consegue escrever? A estrutura do DOM está correta pro jquery achar o lugar certo pra escrever?

Answer (score 4):

O "$(this)" dentro da função de sucesso do Ajax não é uma referência ao seu objeto da classe "comentarios", e sim ao objeto "jqXHR" do Ajax. Para pegar a referência correta, utilize a opção "context" do Ajax, dessa forma:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    context: this,
    success: function(retorno) {
         //agora sim o $(this) está se referindo ao objeto de classe "comentarios"
    }
});
```